# react axios custom hook trigger onClick and on useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, formik

I have a custom hook for the axios calls. I want to use it with useEffect() and also onSumbit() on forms. Right now, **the values that are passed to the `body` of the customHook, are always empty**.  How can I fix this?

axios custom hook:

```
 const useHttp = ({ url, method, body = null, headers = null, autoRun = true }) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    api[method](url, headers, body)
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setloading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!autoRun) {
      return;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [method, url, body, headers]);

  return { response, error, loading, setloading, fetchData };
};

export default useHttp;
```

usage:

```
    const useAuth = () => {
     const [registerFormValues, setRegisterFormValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        doctorId: "",
        personalNumber: "",
      });
    
    const { fetchData } = useHttp({
        autoRun: false,
        method: "post",
        url: "/authentication/register-pacient",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: registerFormValues.name,
          email: registerFormValues.email,
          password: registerFormValues.password,
          doctorId: registerFormValues.doctorId,
          personalNumber: registerFormValues.personalNumber,
        }),
      });
   
    
      const submitHandlerRegister = async (values) => {
        setRegisterFormValues({
          name: values.firstName + " " + values.lastName,
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
          doctorId: values.doctorId,
          personalNumber: values.personalNumber,
        });
        console.log("registerFormValues", registerFormValues);
        fetchData();
      };
    
    return {   
        submitHandlerRegister,
      };
    };
    
    export default useAuth;
```

The `submit handler` is used in a **formik form**. The `values` (submit handler parameter, get the right values from the form)

Comment: The code seems to be fine, you need to provide a reproducible example in codesandbox.io if you need better answer

Comment: In  `submitHandlerRegister` you're calling setState and fetchData at the same time, so there're still previous values in fetch data. What do you think about passing latest values right in `fetchData` function like this `fetchData(values)`?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never a good idea to store same values in two diffrent places. You already have form values in `FormikState`, why do you need duplicate this data in `useAuth`'s state?

When you call `setRegisterFormValues` and trying instantly access `registerFormValues`, there are still previous values. It will be updated during next `render`.

It is more useful to pass up-to-date values directly in `fetchData` function:

```
const fetchData = async (body) => {
    api[method](url, headers, body)
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setloading(false);
      });
  };
```

and usage:

```
const submitHandlerRegister = async (values) => {
    fetchData(values);
};
```

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/sUSe5ODxT24u.png it is not working. The values are still not set  in the setRegisterFormValues. Also I don't think that the fetchData method is called at all in the submit because I added some console logs  ( line 12,13) like this: https://pasteboard.co/Z6Bs5IQZmLRe.png, and they don't appear in the console

Comment: Why do you need these values in the hook state? You already have them in the Formik state.

Comment: I don't actually need that anymore, but still the fetch data method is not called

Comment: Add `console.log` in `fetchData` before calling api and `console.log`  in `submitHandler`. Maybe your form isn't submitting every time.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/MCJq50iXZ31w.png it looks fine, but the object in the backend arrives null.

Comment: You can see what exactly you send to server on the `network` tab in devtools. It may be an issue in `api[method]` function (it would be helpful to see it), on the other hand it may be an issue in your backend.

Comment: the backend controller is fine, the problem is the data that is transmitted to it. https://pasteboard.co/ZCCjbWVaoH0p.png the network:  https://pasteboard.co/DMJ45iGCOH5x.png https://pasteboard.co/cLsKZZt7b3nN.png

Comment: Show the `payload` tab from your second screenshot

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/jYeqxOCCqBRc.png also just for general knowledge, the controller https://pasteboard.co/UGgwIaEEE7QO.png

Comment: You're sending in the request `body` what suppose to be in `headers`.  As I said an issue in you `api[method]`  function. First of all call it that way `api[method](url, body)`, it will work. If you want me to suggest you how to set headers. show me source of the request function

Comment: Ok it worked, it looks like the headers were the problem.  Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

The working code:

```
const useHttp = ({ url, method, body = null, headers = null, autoRun = true }) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async (body) => {
    api[method](url, body)
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setloading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!autoRun) {
      return;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [method, url, body, headers]);

  return { response, error, loading, setloading, fetchData };
};

export default useHttp;


usage:
    
const useAuth = () => {

  const { fetchData } = useHttp({
    autoRun: false,
    method: "post",
    url: "/authentication/register-pacient",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
  });


  const submitHandlerRegister = async (values) => {   
    fetchData(values);
  };

  return {
    submitHandlerRegister,
  };
};

export default useAuth;
```